# IDA: Inconsistency between mouse-over value and stored value?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to RE a program which has a limit of *n* iterations.
I already found the *interesting* part in the disasembled code with static analysis and analysis with the local win32 debugger.

There seems to be a correlation between being BELOW / ABOVE the limit
and a number.

While I'm below the limit the value is set to 1.0. 
If I go above the limit of the value keeps being 0.0

A mouseover tells me the "magic" value.

[image: mouse over during debug]

Now I have two problems:

1. I would like to find out WHAT writes to that address. My idea was to set a write-trace on it - but see no. 2
2. I cannot find the value in memory.
   Right click -> "jump in new window" leads me to `0x0072EB88`
   **The stored value there is 0 altrough IDA is showing me a 1.0 (see first image)**

[image: stored value]

**Manual check**

ESP = `0x0072EB40`

var_838 = `-0x838`

[image: ESP address]

putting it all together: 
`0x0072EB40` + `0x880` - `0x838` => `0x0072EB88`

Can someone help me out please and tell me what my error is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The floating point number `1.0` is represented in memory as `0x3F800000` (see http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html).